# Understanding the proof of an application of the contraction mapping theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have a continuous function $f(t,x)$ defined in a neighbourhood of $(t_0, x_0) \in \Bbb R^2$ for which the condition $|f(t,x_1) - f(t,x_2)| \leq K(x_1-x_2)$, then $dx/dt=f(t,x)$, $x(t_o)=x_0$ has a unique $C^1$ solution $x = \phi(t)$ with $\phi(t_o)=x_0$ for some $\delta$ and $t \in ]t_o-\delta, t_o + \delta[$ .

The first statement in the proof in my analysis textbook (Elementary Classical Analysis) is tripping me up. It states, first choose a ball about $(t_o, x_o)$ such that $|f(t,x)| \leq 1$ and the lipschitz condition holds. Why is this possible and does this mean that $f(t_o,x_o)$ itself has to have absolute value less than $1$. Perhaps this is a typo. Any insights appreciated. Maybe the author means that $|f(x,t)-f(x_o,t)|<1$?

If necessary I can include more of the proof but I don't think the next statements will help clarify this original statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For function satisfying those conditions it's not always possible to pick such a ball. 
The function $f(t,x) = 0.5x$ defined in a ball with radius $1$ around $(0,1000)$ satisfies the conditions since $|f(t, x_0) - f(t,x_1)| = |0.5x_0 - 0.5x_1| \leq 0.5|x_0 -x_1| $. For this function $|f(t,x)| \leq 1$ is never satisfied in its domain.

The for the second $|f(x, t) - f(x_0, t_0)| < 1 $ there's such a ball for which it's satisfied (a ball with radius less than $\frac{1}{K}$ around $(x_0, t_0)$ works). However we can't be sure if that's what the author meant without seeing the rest of the proof.